# Is it possible to retrieve creation date & time of a key-value pair in etcd?

Tags: metadata, key-value, etcd, boltdb

I would like to know if the etcd database stores the date and time of when a key-value pair were created. Additionally, I would also like to know if etcd stores such information about previous versions of a key-value pair as well.

I went through the [etcd.io v5 document](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/) and tried to look for the solution. I was expecting to learn if etcd has any such features due to which the creation date & time of a pair is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is NO

etcd saves revisions as integers, but no timestamps on creation of a key.